# Parse JSON string to javascript object with exact values

Tags: javascript, json

I want to parse a JSON string to a javascript object with the **exact** values of the JSON string.

When I call `JSON.parse` on a JSON string like e.g `{ "someArray": [1.0, 2, 3.7] }` I want exactly the numbers `1.0`, `2` and `3.7` in my object. Unfortunately I get `1`, `2` and `3.7`.

How do  I  parse a JSON string like the one above in an object with the exact values of the string?

Comment: get the data as strings instead of numbers. for what do you need the decimals?

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine a scenario where this would matter.

Comment: @NinaScholz How do I do this? I need the decimals to see if a value was created by a sensor (then it would be 1.0) of if it was entered by a user (then it is a 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript there is no difference between 1.0 and 1 as all numbers are doubles. As far as your parsed data is concerned there is no difference. Try evaluating `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]` in your browser console.

```js
console.log([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

If you really need the string representation of nodes in your JSON, you'd have to use a parser, and walk the parse tree. Something like the [acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) parser, for example.

Comment: If you need to retain the textual representation, it would not be numbers any more, and the best way to make that happen is to ask the provider of the data to generate JSON data that contains strings.

Comment: Is it possible to treat any input element as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing a mistake

```
{ "someArray": [1.0, 2, 3.7] }
```

Data in your array `[1.0,2,3.7]` are integer now and in any programming there are no difference between `1` or `1.0` as integer so change them into string by applying this

```
{ "someArray": ["1.0", "2", "3.7"] }
```

Stay trying new

Answer (score 0):

Convert  the value (of the someArray)  numbers to strings